# BeautifulSoup4 how to get alt text from img inside div

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the alt texts from `class="css-cku98t"` that are inside div `(class_='css-8atqhb')[0]`, but I'm stuck, I tried almost everything.

```
r = requests.get('https://app.mobalytics.gg/lol/champions/senna/build')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all(class_='css-8atqhb')[0]:
    print(i)
```

output:

```
<div class="css-1glrvh"><h3>Starter Items</h3><span>Time Target</span></div> <div class="css-1v6lj4c"><div class="css-19xu9kw"><div class="css-1t2k6vd"><span><img alt="Spectral Sickle" class="css-cku98t" loading="lazy" src="https://fastcdn.mobalytics.gg/assets/lol/images/dd/game-items/3862.png"/></span></div><div class="css-1l6vm6t"><span><img alt="Health Potion" class="css-cku98t" loading="lazy" src="https://fastcdn.mobalytics.gg/assets/lol/images/dd/game-items/2003.png"/></span></div><div class="css-18h675z"><span><img alt="Health Potion" class="css-cku98t" loading="lazy" src="https://fastcdn.mobalytics.gg/assets/lol/images/dd/game-items/2003.png"/></span></div><div class="css-7dime2"><span><img alt="Stealth Ward" class="css-cku98t" loading="lazy" src="https://fastcdn.mobalytics.gg/assets/lol/images/dd/game-items/3340.png"/></span></div></div><p class="css-1ofmdln">@ 13 sec</p></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `'alt'` is an attribute of a `img` element, you can first search for all `'img'` elements before querying the `'alt'` attribute for each found element:

```py
import requests
import bs4

r = requests.get('https://app.mobalytics.gg/lol/champions/senna/build')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
alt_texts = [i['alt'] for i in soup.find_all(class_='css-8atqhb')[0].find_all('img')]
```

Comment: It worked but it's printing outside of list index and it's printing two times

Comment: ['Spectral Sickle', 'Health Potion', 'Health Potion', 'Stealth Ward', "Bami's Cinder", 'Control Ward', 'Boots', 'Frostfire Gauntlet', 'Boots of Swiftness', 'Black Cleaver', 'Frostfire Gauntlet', 'Boots of Swiftness', 'Black Cleaver', 'Rapid Firecannon', "Guinsoo's Rageblade", 'Mortal Reminder']
['Spectral Sickle', 'Health Potion', 'Health Potion', 'Stealth Ward', "Bami's Cinder", 'Control Ward', 'Boots', 'Frostfire Gauntlet', 'Boots of Swiftness', 'Black Cleaver', 'Frostfire Gauntlet', 'Boots of Swiftness', 'Black Cleaver', 'Rapid Firecannon', "Guinsoo's Rageblade", 'Mortal Reminder']

Comment: I added request.get to question

Comment: I edited my answer. In future, please make sure to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly.